# Find 10 number and two letters with Regex.Split()

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem where I should take in the multiple email addresses with a number that is 10 long and has two letters itself, such as `1234567891AB`.

To do this smoothly, I try to use me `Regex.Split()` because there is more communication with the same information and I want to add it to the array.

**Input: (from Outlook)**

```
"Here comes number on the consignment 1020289847AB."
```

I am trying to write a script that looks like this:

```
string[] BODY = Regex.Split(item.body, @"[^\d$]");
```

**Current outpub:** `1020289847`

**The output I want:** `1020289847AB`

Comment: None of these answers doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: From your other questions, it seems you are misusing Stack Overflow as a free crowdsourcing device, i.e. it looks like you are looking for code-monkey-robots. Please, instead of spamming more questions, read some material on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex representation

```
\d+([a-zA-Z]){2}
```

If you want specifically targeting 10 digits in-front

```
\d{10}+([a-zA-Z]){2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need something like:

```
@"\d{10}\D{2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex below.  Grabs 10 digits, and allows lowercase or uppercase for the 2 characters.

```
\d{10}[a-zA-Z]{2}

(\d{10})([a-zA-Z]{2}) - Added Groups for digits and letters
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
string[] BODY = Regex.Split(item.body, @"[^\d{10}[A-Z]{2}$]");
```

This will only match if there's exactly 10 digits, followed by two uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just two character after your numbers, sounds like you just need to use;

```
\d{10}\D{2}
```

Some example matches;

```
3753391729¾~
9446154600Û\
```

Let's code it;

```
string s = "Here comes number on the consignment 1020289847AB.";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{10}\D{2}");
Match match = regex.Match(s);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Output is;

```
1020289847AB
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/7NM0bA).